# Windows 10: Quick Access Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10

Quick acess's Desktop is only showing program icons. Is there a way to make it show everything? Like the Recycle Bin, etc.

It looks like this:

[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove Desktop from Quick Access and add it again?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5WRFeI6.gif  No changes :(

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way. Even if you change Navigation Pane options to 'Show all folders' (so that 'Desktop' and 'Quick Access' are the only two root items), right-clicking Desktop & selecting 'Pin to Quick Access' pins a shortcut to the user's Desktop folder ()your first screenshot), not the root Desktop (your second screenshot).
The quickest routes to the root Desktop are:

1. Set Navigation Pane view options to 'Show all folders'. This lets you select the Desktop from the Navigation Pane:
   [image: Navigation Pane options]
2. Click the '>' at the far left of the Address Bar and select 'Desktop' from the drop-list:
   [image: Address Bar drop-list]
3. Create a shortcut with the following target:

   C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:desktop
   [image: New Shortcut dialog]

Hope this helps,

Keith

Comment: Can you gif it to me? I'm kinda lost on doing this last step. Thx for the answer.

Comment: Added screenshot to above reply.